# Unable to set style-trigger property to custom dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, dependency-properties

I got another problem while working with my usercontrol's xaml file -.-'

I tried to implement an `IsChecked` property to my custom button in order to set a different background colour if the button is checked.

So I created a `DependencyProperty` like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(LeftMenuBtn));

public bool IsChecked
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }
}
```

Then I setup a new style trigger to handle this property:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonEnableStates" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource CheckedStateGradient}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Expression Blend now underlines `Property="IsChecked"` and says:

`The member "IsChecked" is not recognized or is not accessible.`

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the `Style`'s `TargetType` is `Grid` and the property is defined for `LeftMenuBtn`, not going to work like that.

Comment: thanks for your answer. so I tried to change `typeof(LeftMenuBtn)` to `typeof(Grid)` but this does not work too?

Comment: @TorbenJonas: You cannot add properties to existing classes like that, you can however register an [attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) for `LeftMenuBtn`, and use `local:LeftMenuBtn.IsChecked` in the trigger.

Comment: ok thanks for the link going to try this. sorry for this dumb questions but this whole trigger and property topic is a bit confusing to me at the moment^^